# Register value of format 1.4.12

Tags: hardware, cpu-registers

I need to write a value to a HW register, which has the number format.  1.4.12.  I guess the fact they're telling me in the HW specs about the format, that I need to somehow handle the number in a special way.  Could someone give me pointers on what to do?

I guess I cannot just write the value passed to me directly in the register?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Float to fixed conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28483652/float-to-fixed-conversion)

Answer (score 0):

Too little information to make an exact answer. The format 1.4.12 says nothing without further context.

There should be a specification of the format somewhere in the docs, at least if the documentation is a formal paper and complete.

Sometimes, this "specification" is just a brief explanation how bits are ordered in each register -- but then it has to elaborate on exactly how to map data into each bit.