# Float to fixed conversion

Tags: c++, math, floating-point, fixed-point

This is a basic question but I am confused.

I have a register which has the format 1.4.12.  Meaning it takes a float and takes the range -15.9999 - 15.9999, is that correct, or how many nines?  I am confused by the range.

I need to convert a c++ float to fixed point and put it in the register?  Are there any std:: libraries to do that in C?  If not is there any standard code that someone could point me to?

Also, how to convert fixed to float would be good?

Comment: What “register” are you talking about?  CPU registers usually don't work that way.

Comment: What "register"? How do you get those numbers from that "format"? What have you tried so far?

Comment: It is a HW register.

Comment: Hardware register on *what*?

Comment: Binary numbers don't use nines for the limits. It's a binary number. So as .9999 is 9999/10000, in your case it would be 4095/4096.

Comment: I mean how do I know the limit which the float can take?

Comment: Its a 32bit register on some custom HW, where I must represent the number 1.4.12 format.

Comment: Do I really have to spell it out for you? The range is +/- (15 + 4095/4096). That's -15.999755859375 to 15.999755859375.

Comment: Sorry, you don't have to come to a question forum and answer a question, you came here of your own free will, hopefully :)

Comment: This is a bad question, still. No information passed as comment, is added. Nothing clarifies it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fairly simple to do this yourself:

```
typedef int32_t fixed;

fixed float_to_fixed(float x)
{
    return (fixed)(x * 65536.0f / 16.0f);
}
```

Note that this has no range checking so if `x` can possibly be outside the valid range for your fixed point type then you might want to add some checks and either saturate or throw an error as appropriate.

Similarly for conversion in the other direction:

```
float fixed_to_float(fixed x)
{
    return (float)x * 16.0f / 65536.0f;
}
```

(This one does not need any range checking of course.)

Comment: Thanks alot.  I guess this is for 16bit max.  But in my case I have 17. Do I just need to use 32.0f and 2147483647?  Any links or tips to know the range?

Comment: Are you *sure* you have 17 bits ? I assumed that was a typo. It's pretty easy to adapt the above code to whatever fixed point format you need though. If it really is 17 bits then you need to specify what size word is used (24 bits ? 32 bits ?) and whereabouts in the word the 17 bits are located (e.g. MS or LS).

Comment: I've updated the answer now to use a 32 bit word size and put the 17 fixed point bits in the least significant 17 bits of this 32 bit word.

Comment: Yes, some are 17, others 18 and 22 etc...  Each HW register is 32 bits in length.  The place where I put them depends on the register it can be bits 0:16 and others 5:21.  There are many variations.  One word is 32bits.

Comment: OK - well the above examples should be enough to get you started - shifting the bits to the required position within the 32 bit word is easy enough of course.

Comment: @PaulR: Can you expand on why you don't simply multiply by 4096?  I don't understand why you're taking multiple steps...

Comment: @MooingDuck: the compiler will combine the constants resulting in a single multiply, so it amounts to the same thing, but expressing it this way in the code makes the intent more self-evident, as it shows the two constants separately.

Comment: @PaulR: You say "having both constants makes the intent more self-evident", but I have no idea where you got those constants or what they mean.  If I were writing the code, I would have written `static const int fraction_bits = 12;
static const int fraction_adjustment = (1<<fraction_bits); return x * fraction_adjustment;`.  Instead, your code uses `65536.0f`, which I can't figure out... wait, that's 16 bits... oh you're adjusting to the MSB of the result, and then sliding back down to bring the integer part back.  That's weird to my mind.

Comment: @MooingDuck: sure - I guess it just depends on what you are used to - to my mind fixed point has two parameters: word size and position of implied decimal point. So if the word size is 16 bits and there are 4 integer bits to the left of the DP then that translates to 2^16 = 65536 and 2^4 = 16. One could express it even more verbosely I suppose, e.g. 1<<16 and 1<<4 instead of 65536 and 16,

Comment: @PaulR: Interesting.  I view fixed point as simply storing the numerator of a fraction with a fixed denominator (in this case, 4096), and not worrying overmuch about the word size or implied decimal point.  Different points of view is all.

Comment: Yes, like so many things it all depends on how you look at it. Note that fixed point formats are often specified as e.g. 1.31 or 4.12 where the two numbers indicate the number of bits before and after the decimal point.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use fixed-point, then you must implement addition and multiplication operations. In that case, you need to worry about how many bits you have allocated for the fractional part and how many bits allocated for the integer part. And then you can do "shift" operation as your preference.

In the following code-snippet, I've implemented fixed-point by allocating 22 bits for the fractional part and 9 bits for the integer part. (additional bit will be for the sign)

In multiplication, I've first expanded the bit-length of each value to avoid overflow. After multiplication, left shift will happen to keep the same fractional part for the output of multiplication.

In addition, I've added saturation for the output, in order to avoid any overflow (if overflow happens, then output will keep the maximum absolute value that it can keep irrespective of the sign)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define fractional_bits 22
#define fixed_type_bits 32

typedef int32_t fixed_type;
typedef int64_t expand_type;

fixed_type float_to_fixed(float inp)
{
    return (fixed_type)(inp * (1 << fractional_bits));
}

float fixed_to_float(fixed_type inp)
{
    return ((float)inp) / (1 << fractional_bits);
}

fixed_type fixed_mult(fixed_type inp_1, fixed_type inp_2)
{
    return (fixed_type)(((expand_type)inp_1 * (expand_type)inp_2) >> fractional_bits);
}

fixed_type fixed_add(fixed_type inp_1, fixed_type inp_2)
{
    fixed_type inp_1_sign = inp_1 >> (fixed_type_bits - 1);
    fixed_type inp_2_sign = inp_2 >> (fixed_type_bits - 1);
    fixed_type add = inp_1 + inp_2;
    fixed_type add_sign = add >> (fixed_type_bits - 1);

    if (inp_1_sign != inp_2_sign)
    {
        return add;
    }
    else if (add_sign == inp_1_sign)
    {
        return add;
    }
    else if (add_sign == -1)
    {
        return ((1 << (fixed_type_bits - 2)) - 1 + (1 << (fixed_type_bits - 2)));
    }
    else if (add_sign == 1)
    {
        return (1 << (fixed_type_bits - 1));
    }
}
```